# how to unsort after sorting data

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get back the original data after sorting the data here is the code, it runs very slowly:

```
[Rs,iR] = sort(R,1);
for j = 1:length(Rs)
   for q = 1:length(iR)
     if(iR(q) == j)
         R_org(j,1) = Rs(iR(q));

     end
end
```

After using the method shown in comment, I am not getting same answer:

```
K>> R = [8;2;7;9;10]

R =

     8
     2
     7
     9
    10

K>> [Rs,iR] = sort(R,1)

Rs =

     2
     7
     8
     9
    10


iR =

     2
     3
     1
     4
     5

K>> R_org = Rs(iR)

R_org =

     7
     8
     2
     9
    10
```

R and R_org does not match

Comment: You are looking for `R_org = Rs(iR)`

Comment: Corrected error

Comment: is my comment not what you're looking for ?

Comment: I am trying to get R after sorting it. I need to go back to original after i sort arrays with iR i get after sorting R

Comment: @nman84 thus, obchardon comment will do that

Comment: Tried using method shown in the edit

Comment: You need to do it the other way around: `R_org(iR) = Rs`. Then you'll probably want to transpose it.

Comment: ...or preallocate `R_org` to be the proper shape.

Answer (score 2):

Given a list `W`, sorted with `f`, `U = W(f)`, find `g` such that, `W = U(g)`:
`W` -- `f` --> `U` -- `g` --> `W`

Solution:

```matlab
[U, f] = sort(W);
[~, g] = sort(f);
```

("`~`" here means don't care)